# Filament search not working with accessor column

Tags: laravel-filament

### We cant apply search on accessor column,
I got error
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'department_name' in 'where clause'

JobApplication.php (Model)

```
 public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Jobs::class);
}

public function getDepartmentNameAttribute()
{
    return optional($this->job()->withTrashed()->first())->department->name ?? null;
}
```

---

```
Filament JobApplication Resource
   Tables\Columns\TextColumn::make('department_name')
                ->label('Department Name')
                ->searchable(isIndividual: false, isGlobal: true),
```